# Ubuntu 16.04 webdav + apache with auth on mssql

Tags: sql-server, apache, authorization, ubuntu-16.04, webdav

Good day. I want to configure webdav on ubuntu 16.04. For this, I am trying to configure Apache with authorization through the mssql (windows) database.

For example, Google gives a lot of information about connecting with MySQL, but there are no examples with MSSQL.

I am using mod_dbd https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dbd.html

It says how to connect:

```
FreeTDS (for MSSQL and SyBase)
username, password, appname, dbname, host, charset, lang, server
```

But in the installed libraries I did not find freetds

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/apr-util-1:
apr_crypto_openssl-1.so  
apr_dbd_mysql.so   
apr_dbd_sqlite3-1.so  
apr_dbm_db.so                           
apr_crypto_openssl.so    
apr_dbd_odbc-1.so  
apr_dbd_sqlite3.so    
apr_ldap-1.so                           
apr_dbd_mysql-1.so       
apr_dbd_odbc.so
apr_dbm_db-1.so
apr_ldap.so
```

my cfg apache file:

```
DBDPersist on
DBDExptime 300
DBDMax 10
DBDMin 1
DBDriver ?

DBDParams "host=192.168.0.8;dbname=db;username=sa;password=pass"

NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@domain

DocumentRoot /var/www/webdavhtml/
<Directory /srv/nfs/webdav/>
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Alias /webdav /srv/nfs/webdav
<Location /webdav>
  DAV On
  AuthName "webdav"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider dbd
  AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT encrypt(password) AS PassHash FROM dbo.db WHERE Login = %s"
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

maybe there is a ready-made example of authorization in the webdav with apache and mssql? Thank!